# Problem in sorting contours according to contour area size

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, watershed

I am segmenting rocks. To compare the results of segmentation, I :

1. Find the contours of the binary image of the segmented image
2. Find the contour area
3. Sort the area
4. Find the n largest and compare it with the ground truth

The problem however is :

-> The sorting does not give the n largest, say 5, contours. I dont understand why.

Here is the input image :

[image: Input Image]

All the contours after sorting :

[image: all contours]

And, the first 5 contours image :

[image: 5 contours]

The result I expect is just the first 5 or n number of largest contours. To be specific , the first and 2nd largest should be the large brown colored rocks on the right side of the rgb image.

The code for sorting is referred from [page 417](http://file.allitebooks.com/20170108/Learning%20OpenCV%203.pdf)

My code(rough part of it) to show the first 5 contours is given below :

```
 // Sorting by descending order
struct AreaCmp {    
AreaCmp(const vector<float>& _areas) : areas(&_areas) {}    
bool operator()(int a, int b) const { return (*areas)[a] > (*areas)[b]; }   
 const vector<float>* areas;};


int main{

  std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point>> contours;
  std::vector<cv::Vec4i> hierarchy;// There is no hierarchy formed because of CV_RETR_LIST

  cv::findContours(input_image, contours, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);//CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE

  std::vector<int> sortIdx(contours.size());
  std::vector<float> areas(contours.size());

  for( int n = 0; n < (int)contours.size(); n++)
  {
      sortIdx[n] = n;
      areas[n] = cv::contourArea(contours[n], false);
  }

  std::sort(sortIdx.begin(), sortIdx.end(), AreaCmp(areas));

  FINROC_LOG_PRINT(DEBUG, "sortIdx size", (int)sortIdx.size());
  FINROC_LOG_PRINT(DEBUG, "contours size", (int)contours.size());

  int q = 0;
  for( int n = 0; n < (int)sortIdx.size(); n++)
  {
      int idx = sortIdx[n];
      cv::drawContours(input_rgb_image, contours, idx, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 1, 8, hierarchy);
      q++;
      if(q > 5) break; // to draw only the first 5

  }
}
```

Comment: *The sorting does not give the n largest, say 5, contours* What is the **input** of the `sort` function? (Not the picture, the actual numbers). What is the **output** of the `sort` function? (Not the picture, the actual numbers).

Comment: The inputs for the sort function are : start index, last index and a comparing function.  More detail given in : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/

Comment: One more thing I dont' understand is, the number of contours after looking at the RGB image with contours should be around 25-30. But when I ask for the contours.size(), i get 1000+ contours.

Comment: I know what *kind* of input `std::sort` expects. I'm asking you to show the *specific numbers* you are feeding to it. Specifically, the values in `areas`.

Comment: The values of areas are anywhere between 4 to 41.5

Comment: I think @n.m.'s reckoning is that dependent upon the values of the top 5 contours after sorting, you will be able to deduce whether the sorting function is broken, or whether your understanding/assumptions about the contour area are incorrect. I'm curious what the output would be if you rendered the 5 largest, but without the largest contour. Could it be that those small contours are in fact a cut out from the largest contour?

Comment: POST THE VALUES. Don't describe them in colourful prose. I believe I have mentioned the word *specific* somewhere.

Comment: @NicholasBetsworth: Yeah. I think there could be a possibility of that. There should a problem then in the findcontours function. Right?

Comment: @n.m : oh. sorry. there are some thousand values. Do you want all of them?Or I can show the first 50 or so. Is that ok?

Comment: Your claim is that you have a problem in sorting. In order to validate that claim, we need to see both the input and the output of sorting. Seeing a part of the input or part of the output doesn't quite help. If you want to show 50 values, then you need to sort these 50 values, not the entire 1000, and show the 50 output values as well. Then we can see whether the problem is indeed in sorting.

Comment: By the way if you expect the input of sorting to contain tens of values but in fact you get 1000, then the problem is evidently not in sorting but elsewhere.

Comment: @n.m. I think you got it right. The problem is elsewhere, specifically in findcontours because it is finding more contours than expected.

Comment: There are apparently two different problems. One is that you are finding more contours that you expect, and the other is that those contours are absolutely not the contours you want. I suspect these are two sides of the same coin. Look at the output picture. It contains a contour that is the *outside* of the big area you hope to subdivide into contours, and perhaps small contours that kinda fall between the rocks, and none that encircle the rocks themselves. I guess your contour finding algorithm cannot tell inside from outside. The 1000 contours you find are probably all between the rocks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199838/discussion-between-vom-and-n-m).